# ¿Es correcto usar la expresión "fruta de la pasión"?

Tags: expresiones, rae

Seguro que mucho habréis visto la expresión "fruta de la pasión" en los ingredientes de alguna bebida, o en la narración de algún anuncio, o para promocionar algún producto que lleve *maracuyá*.

Según la RAE, *[maracuyá](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OLhpmKa)* es el nombre que recibe el fruto comestible de la pasionaria. Proviene del portugués *maracujá*. Por su parte, la *[pasionaria](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S4EPSef)* es una planta que recibe su nombre *por la semejanza que parece existir entre las diferentes partes de la flor y los atributos de la pasión de Jesucristo*. Lo que me hace especial gracia porque cuando se usa "fruta de la pasión" suena como sensual, seductor, cuando en realidad el tipo de "pasión" al que hace referencia es uno completamente diferente.

Sin embargo, la RAE recoge el término *[flor de la pasión](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I6Rb5ZS)* para nombrar a la flor de la pasionaria, aunque el propio nombre de "pasionaria" también hace referencia a la flor de dicha planta. No sé si por aquí se agarrarán los publicistas para defender el uso de "fruta de la pasión".

Así pues, ¿sería correcto (o aceptable) el uso de "fruta de la pasión" para decir "maracuyá"? ¿O cada publicista que usa "fruta de la pasión" merecería una [colleja](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9oDk6gd%7C9oExe53)?

Comment: Entiendo que esta pregunta pueda rayar en el *off-topic* por ser algo subjetiva. Si es así intentaré modificarla o la retiraré con toda tranquilidad.

Comment: ¿Por qué no va a ser correcto? El lenguaje está lleno de expresiones en las que el sentido de una palabra ha mudado con el paso del tiempo. A veces, incluso la escritura (*en olor de multitudes*, *montar el pollo*...)

Comment: Caramba, interesantísima investigación que me ha dejado anonadado. Fíjate que incluso en Radio 3 hay un programa llamado [Flor de pasión](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/audios/flor-de-pasion/) de música de los sesenta. No creo que lo usen para hablar de Jesucristo, ni mucho menos, por lo que me da la sensación de que, como con esta pregunta, el término ha ido derivando a partir de que alguien lo interpretó como pasión amorosa.

Comment: A mí me parece que es como preguntar si es correcto llamar *la chispa de la vida* a la Coca-Cola porque viene de un eslogan publicitario. O si es correcto llamar *rímel* a la sombra de ojos porque viene de una marca comercial. O *Groenlandia* a ese territorio cuando no es verde, sino que el nombre fue un ardid de su decubridor para atraer colonos (publicidad ya hace un milenio). El lenguaje se forma de muchas maneras y, si una expresión tiene éxito y no violenta la gramática, no veo por qué debe considerarse incorrecta solo por tener un interés comercial en su origen.

Comment: @Gorpik tu comentario me parece que podría ser una respuesta bastante acertada, ¿te animas? Me ha llamado mucho la atención lo de Groenlandia sobre todo.

Comment: Tal vez se podría reformular como: _en qué momento pasión toma el cariz romántico en lugar del relacionado con la muerte de Jesucristo_.

Comment: Vale, he escrito una respuesta basada en la idea general de mi comentario.

Comment: Por cierto, veo [en Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pasi%C3%B3n&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpasi%C3%B3n%3B%2Cc0) que la palabra _pasión_ tuvo un subidón de uso a partir de finales del siglo XIX, bajó hacia los 1970 y ahora vuelve a subir. Lo mismo tiene que ver con esta ampliación de su significado para pasar a designar cosas románticas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El lenguaje se forma de muchas maneras y no debemos considerar que unas son más válidas que otras por cuestiones morales. Si una expresión restringida a un campo de aplicación concreto hace fortuna, puede acabar incorporándose al registro general con el mismo significado o con otro. La etimología es útil para entender el origen de las palabras, pero no debe usarse para restringir el lenguaje.

Actualmente no es raro que la publicidad utilice expresiones para referirse a sus productos con el fin de hacerlos más atractivos. Y no tan actualmente: hay ejemplos de expresiones y nombres dados por motivos publicitarios desde hace muchos siglos. Uno que me gusta especialmente es el de Groenlandia, cuyo significado original es *tierra verde*, pese a tratarse principalmente de un inmenso glaciar. Al parecer, Erik el Rojo le puso ese nombre para atraer colonos al territorio. ¿Es incorrecto usar el nombre por deberse a un motivo engañoso? No. El nombre hizo fortuna y se ha quedado.

Con el maracuyá pasa algo parecido. Nadie puede obligarnos a creer que el maracuyá sea afrodisiaco, de igual forma que nadie puede obligarnos a creer que Groenlandia es verde. Pero si la expresión ha tenido éxito, en buena parte porque el carácter tropical de la fruta nos hace asociar más esa *pasión* a la amorosa que a la de Cristo, ¿cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 2):

"Maracuyá" y "Fruta de la pasión" son distintas formas de llamar a la misma cosa. El nombre indigena es Maracuyá, y el nombre con el que es conocida es "Fruta de la pasión". De hecho en España no se utilizaba la palabra indígena hasta los años 80 en que se lanzó comercialmente un refresco de Maracuyá.

**Maracuyá**: Fruto de Passiflora edulis

**Flor de la pasión**: Flor de Passiflora edulis

**Fruta de la pasión**: Fruto de Passiflora edulis

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta a la pregunta. Intenta releer el enunciado otra vez para ceñirte a lo pregunta, pues actualmente esto es una recopilación de datos que ya estaban presentes en el enunciado.

Comment: Esta respuesta me ha hecho investigar en el mapa de diccionarios, encontrando datos curiosos: efectivamente, el término _maracuyá_ no se recogió en el diccionario hasta el 2001, así que es muy moderno. Sin embargo, el término _pasionaria_ ya existía en el de 1780, y ahí se dice lo siguiente: _"[...] porque el fruto de esta planta se parece en algo á la granada, la llamáron los Españoles **GRANADILLA**"_. Así que busqué _granadilla_ y bingo, es el nombre que se le dio al fruto de la planta hasta precisamente 2001, última versión que recoge el término (en la actual ha desaparecido).