# ¿"Parchita" proviene de "Passion Fruit"?

Tags: etimología, venezuela

No hay pocas palabras de uso común en Venezuela que sean importadas (machucadas) de otros idiomas, por ejemplo:

- Macundal
- Guachimán
- Musiú

La palabra *Parchita* (que en Venezuela es *"Maracuyá"*), ¿viene de *"Passion Fruit"*?

Answer (score 4):

Alcanzo a leer en la breve muestra que pone Google Libros en [Quinientas y una pequeñas historias](https://books.google.cl/books?id=u9NrAAAAMAAJ&q=parcha%20cumanagoto&dq=parcha%20cumanagoto&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGl-aykJr9AhXVk4kEHV8ZCF04ChDoAXoECAEQAg) de Juan Röhl:

> La palabra "parcha" -y su diminutivo "parchita"- nombre genérico con que se conocen las ocho o diez especies que existen en Venezuela de las diversas plantas pasiflóreas, es una voz indígena de probable origen cumanagoto.

Sin embargo, este posible origen cumanagoto  se contradice con lo documentado en [The Journal of Botany, British and Foreign](https://books.google.cl/books?id=C0A-AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA24&dq=parcha%20cumanagoto&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgpsCHkZr9AhXKjYkEHR4rDrkQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=parcha%20cumanagoto&f=false), donde indican que *paicururu* es cumanagoto, mientras que *parcha* es criollo.

Como sea, ambos estarían sugiriendo que la denominación es previa a cualquier influencia inglesa.

Si tu suposición se basa en que *parchita* suena parecido a *passion fruit*, en realidad esa paronimia pudo haber surgido a partir de la denominación original, *pasionaria*, y esta a su vez del latín *passio*, que significa "sufrimiento". La etimología de la fruta de la pasión es entretenida, se habló de ella en [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17563/6915).

Answer (score 2):

Según el DLE, [**parchita**](https://dle.rae.es/parchita) es:

> 1. f. *Ven*. **parcha.**
>
> 2. f. *Ven*. Fruto de la parcha, que se caracteriza ....

y a su vez [**parcha**](https://dle.rae.es/parcha) es:

> 1. f. Nombre genérico ... [de] diversas plantas de la familia de las pasifloráceas.

Pero las [**pasifloráceas**](https://dle.rae.es/pasiflor%C3%A1ceo) son:

> . adj. Bot. Dicho de una hierba o de un arbusto... originarios de países cálidos, principalmente de América del Sur; p. ej., la pasionaria.

Por lo que parece que parchita si puede proceder de pasionaria o flor de la pasión, pero no está claro que sea a través del inglés "Passion Fruit".